# Robotium test case is not working with gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, gradle, robotium

I am using Robotium for my test case. When i am using eclipse for run a test case it is working and showing 2 fail result but when i am using gradle for test case it is showing BUILD SUCCESSFUL.But in my code 2 fail results.

I am using this command - **gradle clean connectedCheck build**

My **build.gradle file**--

```
buildscript {  repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'


android {
 compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1'

sourceSets {
 main {
  manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
  java.srcDirs = ['src']
  resources.srcDirs = ['src']
  aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
  renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
  res.srcDirs = ['res']
  assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
}
 instrumentTest.setRoot('MyTestCase')
instrumentTest { 
        java.srcDirs = ['MyTestCase/src'] 
        manifest.srcFile file('MyTestCase/AndroidManifest.xml') 
        resources.srcDirs = ['MyTestCase/src'] 
        res.srcDirs = ['MyTestCase/res'] 
        assets.srcDirs = ['MyTestCase/assets'] 
    }
 }

dependencies {
 compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
 }

lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
}


 }
```

Comment: After some R&D I get solution of my question . MyTestCase(Test case file) should be in  src folder.